# How can I use local.xml to hide the currency switcher Magento1 RWD?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, currency, rwd-theme

Our store accepts USD and for other currencies, we use paypal. I need to hide the currency switcher on the RWD theme.  I've tried variations of this in local.xml:

```
<layout>
  <default>
    <remove name="currency-switcher" />
  </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only currency instead of currency-switcher

try this:

```
<layout>
   <default>
      <remove name="currency" />
   </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: I swore I had tried this. I think I left out the <default> tags.